# I'm trying to detect the skip add button on you tube with selenium(python)

Tags: python-3.x, automation, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using idle and selenium.
this is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')


def check_exist_by_class():
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-ad-skip-button ytp-button")
        #time.sleep(1)
        return 0
    except NoSuchElementException:
        #time.sleep(1)
        return 1

while True:     
    print(check_exist_by_class())
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I'm only getting 1 even if the skip add button is visible. tried using the x path but the x path for the button changes with the window size.

**Update-** 
X path doesn't change with the window side. its kind of random. Any idea how to click the skip add button with selenium?

X path s of few ad buttons:

```
    ***//*[@id="skip-button:3f"]/span/button
    //*[@id="skip-button:2v"]/span/button
    //*[@id="skip-button:2v"]/span/button
    //*[@id="skip-button:a"]/span/button
    //*[@id="skip-button:a"]/span/button
    //*[@id="skip-button:a"]/span/button
    //*[@id="skip-button:2b"]/span/button***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might not be what you asked for but alternatively you can just get an adblocker for Youtube and load that extension in Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

path_to_extension = r'C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\Desktop\1.9.0_0'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('load-extension=' + path_to_extension)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.create_options()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: I was trying to develop my own program to automatically skip the ad. I'll try this method too. Thanks anyway.  : )